# Show that there are infinitely many integers $n$ with a given number of divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that there are infinitely many integers $n$ with a given number of divisors, but at most finitely many $n$ with a given sum of divisors.

Sorry no useful attempt this time, any help on solution/hint is highly appreciated !

---

I need to prove

there are infinitely many $n$ such that $\tau (n)  =  k$   $(\color{purple}{\text{solved using hints from :  Ethan/DanZ/DarthGeek
}}$)

but there are only finitely may $n$ such that $\sigma(n) = k$

Comment: What is $k$? Is it dependent on $n$?

Comment: yes $k$ is some known fixed number constant

Comment: for example : $k = 2$, we need to prove that there are infinitely many numbers whose divisors are only $2$.  (All prime numbers fit this requirement I think...)

Comment: Then it would not be dependent on $n$, so it would be no. Not yes.

Comment: thats right ! it can be any arbitrary number $k \gt 1$, see that i have invented $k$, its not part of the actual problem... actual problem is before the horizontal line...

Comment: @rsadhvika You're right, all prime numbers have $\tau(p) = 2$. How many divisors does $p^3$ have if $p$ is prime? $p^4$?

Comment: There are infinitely many primes. If $p$ is prime, $p^{k-1}$ has $k$ divisors.

Comment: number of divisors =  $(\text{exponent} + 1)$ right ?

Comment: Oh I see... for a given $k$, we can always construct a number $p^{k-1}$ and since there are infinitely many primes $p$.... thanks I can conclude xD

Comment: sum of divisors proof looks bit tricky though, could you please help on that too :)

Comment: I know sum of divisors  =  $\prod \limits_{1\le i\le \cdots }\dfrac{p_i^{k_i+1}-1}{p_i-1}$

Comment: If you think about it, you can derive the fact that only finitely many $n$ have a given number of divisors from the fact that the sum of the divisors of $n$ is greater than $n$.

Comment: :O good question to read , so at the end we need to find boundary for $\sigma(n)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question for the number of divisors is already set in the comments: for every prime $p$, $p^{k-1}$ has $k$ divisors, hence $d(n)=k$ has an infinite number of solutions since there are an infinite number of primes.

On the other hand, the sum-of-divisors function
$$\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d$$
is a multiplicative function, i.e. $gcd(a,b)=1$ implies $\sigma(ab)=\sigma(a)\sigma(b)$. This gives that if $\sigma(n)=k$, $n$ cannot have more than $\log_3 k$ prime divisors, since for any prime power $p^r$ we have $\sigma(p^r)\geq 3$. Moreover, the biggest prime dividing $n$ cannot exceed $k$, since $\sigma(m)\geq m$, and for the same reason the biggest exponent $r$ such that the prime power $p^r$ divides $n$ cannot exceed $\log_2 k$. This gives that the number of positive integers $n$ such that $\sigma(n)=k$ is (crudely) bounded by:
$$2^{\pi(k)}\cdot(\log_2 k)^{\log_3 k}.$$

Comment: The shapes of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#mediaviewer/File:Divisor.svg and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#mediaviewer/File:Sigma_function.svg certainly support that!

Comment: so the proof hinges on the fact that there can only be finitely many prime powers in the prime factorization of $n$ such that $\sigma(n)=k$ ; using these available prime numbers we can construct only finitely many numbers. Just brilliant xD ! thank you very much :)

Comment: We could also observe that $\sigma(n)\geq 1+n$, so that, if $\sigma(n)=k$, we have $n\leq k-1$.

Comment: yes yes! thats a very useful observation which bounds $n$ xD